# UITextView with rounded corners

Tags: iphone

in many iPhone apps I could see UITextView with rounded corners. Is there a simple way to achieve this? or do I need to create a custom UITextView? any links to examples showing how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round the corners of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047818/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-button)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you are using iOS 3+, you can do the following:

```
myTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Comment: Just let other Xamarin users know, you can use this code, and don't need to worry about QuartzCore. (fyi, I'm on Xamarin iOS 8.10.3.2, targetting iOS 8.4)

Answer (score 11):

Add **QuartzCore** framework to the app and then

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


UITextView* txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
txtView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
txtView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 7):

Just a quick reminder: you can do it easily from the the stroyboard/xib:

[image]

Or create an extension, and set it programmatically or through the storyboard

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I have found is to put the Rounded Rect button with no text under the UITextView, take the UITextView smaller than button.

Done.

Answer (score 5):

#### Swift 4.2

```
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

Comment: IMO Its the modern answer to an old problem. As there was no swift answer already here, i simply provided it. I belive more people will come here looking for the swift answer than the obj-c answer as this tops google search if you search for `UITextView rounded corner swift`

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out my library called [DCKit](https://github.com/andrew8712/DCKit). It's written on the latest version of **Swift**.

You'd be able to make a rounded corner text view/button/text field from the Interface builder directly:

[image: DCKit: rounded button]

It also has many other cool features, such as text fields with validation, controls with borders, dashed borders, circle and hairline views etc.