# How to round the corners of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, rounded-corners

I have a rectangle image (jpg) and want to use it to fill the background of a button with rounded corner in xcode.

I wrote the following:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, cardWidth, cardHeight);
button.frame = frame;
[button setBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, the button I get with that approach doesn't have its corners rounded: it is instead a plain rectangle that looks exactly like my original image.  How can I get instead an image with rounded corner to represent my button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 446, accepted):

I tried the following solution with the UITextArea and I expect this will work with UIButton as well.

First of all import this in your .m file -

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then in your `loadView` method add following lines

```
    yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
    yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Also works with the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" inspector

Comment: Works for swift also!  Just change YES to true.

Comment: in 2023 you don't import anything

Answer (score 134):

You can achieve by this RunTime Attributes

[image]

we can make custom button.just see screenshot attached.

**kindly pay attention :**

**in runtime attributes to change color of border follow this instruction**

1. create category class of CALayer
2. in h file

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* borderIBColor;
   ```
3. in m file:

   ```
   -(void)setBorderIBColor:(UIColor*)color {
       self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
   }

   -(UIColor*)borderIBColor {
       return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];
   }
   ```

now onwards to set border color check screenshot

[image: updated answer]

thanks

Comment: Just me or is the information in the answer incomplete? It doesn't really work. Update: it works as long as I do not specify `borderColor`. But then it always uses black for the borderColor.

Comment: Extended answer: The color set in the IB is likely of UIColor type which does not work with borderColor, which is of CGColorRef. Or something like that. So a solution is to create a category on CALayer, with something like `@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor* borderIBColor;` (which does not clash with some other name) in header file, and the implementation is: `-(void)setBorderIBColor:(UIColor*)color{self.borderColor = color.CGColor;}
-(UIColor*)borderIBColor{return [UIColorcolorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];}`

Comment: If you don't want a border color, set the borderRadius to 0 and you won't have one!

Comment: What about Swift?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey
i create extension of CALayer.

Comment: the attributes are : borderWidth, cornerRadius and borderColor
more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089222/1083128

Answer (score 15):

*Pushing to the limits* corner radius up to get a circle:

```
    self.btnFoldButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.btnFoldButton.frame.height/2.0;
```

[image]

If button frame is an square it does not matter frame.height or frame.width. Otherwise use the largest of both ones.

Answer (score 14):

You may want to check out my library called [DCKit](https://github.com/andrew8712/DCKit). It's written on the latest version of **Swift**.

You'd be able to make a rounded corner button/text field from the Interface builder directly:

[image: DCKit: rounded button]

It also has many other cool features, such as text fields with validation, controls with borders, dashed borders, circle and hairline views etc.

Answer (score 10):

```
UIButton* closeBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 90, 35)];
//Customise this button as you wish then
closeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
closeBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;//Important
```

Answer (score 8):

Import **QuartCore framework** if it is not there in your existing project, then import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in **viewcontroller.m**

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); // set values as per your requirement
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 4):

First set width=100 and Height=100 of button

> Objective C Solution

```
YourBtn1.layer.cornerRadius=YourBtn1.Frame.size.width/2;
YourBtn1.layer.borderColor=[uicolor blackColor].CGColor;
YourBtn1.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
```

> Swift 4 Solution

```
YourBtn1.layer.cornerRadius = YourBtn1.Frame.size.width/2
YourBtn1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
YourBtn1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try my code. Here you can set all properties of UIButton like text colour, background colour, corner radius, etc.

```
extension UIButton {
    func btnCorner() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Now call like this

```
yourBtnName.btnCorner()
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

For **Objective C**:

```
submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
submitButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

For **Swift**:

```
submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
submitButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a rounded corner only to one corner or two corners, etc... read this post:

[ObjC] – UIButton with rounded corner - http://goo.gl/kfzvKP

It's a XIB/Storyboard subclass. Import and set borders without write code.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

> updated for Swift 3 :

used below code to make UIButton corner round:

```
 yourButtonOutletName.layer.cornerRadius = 0.3 *
        yourButtonOutletName.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 4 Update

I also tried many options still i wasn't able to get my UIButton round cornered.
I added the corner radius code inside the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` Solved My issue.

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        anyButton.layer.cornerRadius = anyButton.frame.height / 2
    }
```

Also we can adjust the cornerRadius as follows:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        anyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10 //Any suitable number as you prefer can be applied 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer which sets a border too (making it more like a button) is here ... [How to set rectangle border for custom type UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854306/how-to-set-rectangle-border-for-custom-type-uibutton/7672651#7672651)

Answer (score 1):

For iOS SWift 4

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
button.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use outlet connection and didSet function for your button on the view;

```
 @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!{
        didSet {
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            button.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        }
    }
```