# How to change the shape of button in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to make a roundrectangular button i applied the following code but its not working. Plz help me
[image]

```
login = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    CGFloat xbuttonpadding = CGRectGetMinX(password.frame);
    CGFloat ybuttonpadding = CGRectGetMaxY(password.frame) + xpadding;
    CGFloat widthloginbutton = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - widthpassword;
    CGFloat heightloginbutton = CGRectGetHeight(username.frame) +10;
    login.frame= CGRectMake(xbuttonpadding, ybuttonpadding, widthloginbutton, heightloginbutton);
    login.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [login setTitle:@"login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [login addTarget:self action:@selector(show:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round the corners of a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047818/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-button)

Comment: `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` was deprecated in iOS 7. Follow @ShamasS link to round the corners yourself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all import this in your .m file -

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then in your loadView method add following lines

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
login.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5f;
login.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: increase corner radius

Comment: If i want to do frame circular then what to do?

Comment: corner radius should be equal of the button height