# How to cut of corners of UIButton, not round them?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I would like to cut the corners off of a UIButton in swift.

I know how to set a corner radius but I'd like to cut the corners.

```
// what I DON'T want, rounded corners
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.height / 2
```

Cut off corners are for me:

[image]

Comment: See following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047818/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-button

Comment: what do you mean by cut of corners?

Comment: I added a picture to better show it

Comment: use yellow image as background of uibutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CAShapeLayer with the desired path like this

[image]

```
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .red
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 40)
view.addSubview(button)

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor

let cutSize:CGFloat = 20
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: button.bounds.midY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cutSize, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: button.bounds.maxX-cutSize, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: button.bounds.maxX, y: button.bounds.midY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: button.bounds.maxX-cutSize, y: button.bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cutSize, y: button.bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: button.bounds.midY))

layer.path = path.cgPath
button.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
```